# Why NPM fails to install mysql?

Tags: node.js, npm

NPM fails to install mysql on Windows 7 64-bit. I deleted npm-cache, made sure I'm running correct npm.cmd, used Windows commandline and Cygwin64 terminal but it didn't help.

Command line:

```
npm install mysql --save
npm ERR! path C:\development\domovnik\domovnik-backend\node_modules\mysql\node_modules\string_decoder
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\development\domovnik\domovnik-backend\node_modules\mysql\node_modules\string_decoder' -> 'C:\development\domovnik\domovnik-backend\node_modules\mysql\node_modules\.string_decoder.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-01T19_36_05_576Z-debug.log
```

Versions:

```
npm version
{ 'adonis-api-app': '4.1.0',
  npm: '5.6.0',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  cldr: '32.0',
  http_parser: '2.8.0',
  icu: '60.1',
  modules: '57',
  napi: '3',
  nghttp2: '1.29.0',
  node: '8.11.2',
  openssl: '1.0.2o',
  tz: '2017c',
  unicode: '10.0',
  uv: '1.19.1',
  v8: '6.2.414.54',
  zlib: '1.2.11' }
```

File [C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-05-01T19_36_05_576Z-debug.log](https://www.uschovna.cz/download/MMUEB5L5KF49G7RL-P6K/RE4UMUCRHW/).

Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: A couple of suggestions, 1. Try deleting the `node_modules` directory and run `npm i` again. 2. Try removing the `package-lock.json` and install the dependencies again.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. But after uninstaling nodejs and installing the latest version it started work.